# check array contains the same numbers

Tags: c#, predicate, dice

I am trying to make a simple dice game. it's entirely in the console.
a user can set an infinite number of dices. and then the game has to tell how many rolls it took for all the dices to be 6 at the same time.

I have tried something like this,

```
    int i = 0;
    int[] throws = new int[4000];
    bool success = false;
    do
    {
        throws[1] = dice.Next(1, 7);
        throws[2] = dice.Next(1, 7);
        throws[3] = dice.Next(1, 7);
        throws[4] = dice.Next(1, 7);
        throws[5] = dice.Next(1, 7);
        throws[6] = dice.Next(1, 7);

        if (Array.TrueForAll(throws, 6))
        {
            success = true;
        }
        i++;
    } while (success != true);
```

but **trueforall** says fails with something called predicate, which i have been unable to understand fully.

is there another way ?

a bit stuck here.. hope someone can help with this.

Comment: See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x(v=vs.110).aspx). The second parameter should be a function that returns true if what you want to check holds for an item, and false otherwise.

Comment: if throws is a bool[], you'll need throws.TrueForAll(b => b)

Comment: @vc74 throws are int[] throws = new int[4000];

Comment: @andrelange91 There's your second problem then. You should only make your array as large as it needs to be, otherwise your `TrueForAll` is going to be checking each of those extra indices - and they may not all satisfy your predicate.

Comment: @andrelange91 Then you can use: if (throws.All(i => (i == 6))

Comment: @hnefatl how do i determine my size then ? based on the users input ?

Comment: @andrelange91 If the size is not known, use a List<int> instead of an array, the Linq code I sent you should still work

Comment: @andrelange91 Yes, use a `List<int>` and use the `.Add` method to add new items. You'll should then use the `All` extension method on the list, rather than `Arrays.TrueForAll`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A predicate is a method that takes one object/variable as argument, checks a condition on that and returns either `true` or `false`.. now to the issue:

instead of doing:

```
 if (Array.TrueForAll(throws, 6))
```

do:

```
 if (Array.TrueForAll(throws, x => x == 6))
```

but what is this?

```
x => x == 6
```

is exactly that predicate we are talking about

is a lambda that can be read as:

> take every element in the array, in a variable X. now evaluate if X ==
>   6

Comment: See also the example here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @andrelange91 share the love (and save people's time) and mark this as answered if this resolved your question!

Comment: @RufusL now done, just wanted to run it to be sure it all worked out ^^